# Present all the literature in the Bib file in the bibliography list, even though some of them are not cited in the document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Now I need a command like \nocite{*} in the macro package of natbib in order to solve the problem showed in the tile. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[hyperref,UTF8]{ctex} 
\usepackage[style=gb7714-2015ay,maxcitenames=3,gbnamefmt=lowercase,sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  andincite = {and},
  and       = {and},
}

\addbibresource{lcgxm.bib}

\begin{document}

Thanks for your help! \\ \\
\indent \textcite{Kodan2013} \\
\indent \textcite{wsggzh2015} \\
\parencite{wsggzh2015} \\
%\parencite{wsgpark2007} % How do I present this paper in the bibloography even if I do not cite it in the main body text?
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My Bib file is:

```
@article{wsggzh2015,
author = {汪三贵 and 郭子豪},
journal = {贵州社会科学},
number = {05},
pages = {147--150},
title = {论中国的精准扶贫},
volume = {305},
year = {2015}
}
 

 @article{Kodan2013,
author = {Kodan, Anand S. and Chhikara, Kuldip S.},
journal = {Management and Labour Studies},
month = {feb},
number = {1-2},
pages = {103--133},
title = {{A Theoretical and Quantitative Analysis of Financial Inclusion and Economic Growth}},
volume = {38},
year = {2013}
}


@article{wsgpark2007,
author = {汪三贵 and Park, Albert and Chaudhuri, Shubham and Datt, Gaurav},
journal = {管理世界},
keywords = {nmgsocial,poverty,poverty_performance},
number = {1},
pages = {56--64},
title = {中国新时期农村扶贫与村级贫困瞄准},
year = {2007}
}
```

Comment: try `\nocite{wsgpark2007}`

Comment: `\nocite{*}`  works with biblatex too. Did you try?

Comment: `\nocite` is a core latex command, not defined by the natbib package.

Comment: I was about to write what David said above, but to be fair `biblatex` reimplements all `\...cite` commands and also reimplements `\nocite`, so pointing to the LaTeX kernel definition might not be that useful. But the bottom line remains: `\nocite` can be used without `natbib` (it is not a `natbib` command like, say, `\citep`) and it also works with `biblatex` (in both the 'cite all available entries' `\nocite{*}` and 'cite a specific key' `\nocite{<key>}` senses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\nocite` does the trick:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[hyperref,UTF8]{ctex} 
\usepackage[style=gb7714-2015ay,maxcitenames=3,gbnamefmt=lowercase,sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  andincite = {and},
  and       = {and},
}

\addbibresource{lcgxm.bib}

\begin{document}

Thanks for your help! \\ \\
\indent \textcite{Kodan2013} \\
\indent \textcite{wsggzh2015} \\
\parencite{wsggzh2015} \\
%\parencite{wsgpark2007} % How do I present this paper in the bibloography even if I do not cite it in the main body text?
\nocite{wsgpark2007} % <-- \nocite does the trick
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]